# Packets sent in IPv4

Tags: ipv4

I'm just trying to understnd how packets work.
So if i hypothetically had a image of a size of 1mb which is 1,000,000 bytes and the maximum packet size for a IPv4 packet is 65,536 bytes does that mean that optimally there would be only 16 packets sent?
Sorry if this a dumb question i'm just doing a presentation for school and would like to know as much as possible.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

[**Firstly you need to understand the TCP/IP Networking Model**](https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1757634&seqNum=2)

A networking model, sometimes also called either a networking architecture or networking blueprint, refers to a comprehensive set of documents. Individually, each document describes one small function required for a network; collectively, these documents define everything that should happen for a computer network to work. Some documents define a protocol, which is a set of logical rules that devices must follow to communicate. Other documents define some physical requirements for networking. For example, a document could define the voltage and current levels used on a particular cable when transmitting data.

You can think of a networking model as you think of an architectural blueprint for building a house. Sure, you can build a house without the blueprint. However, the blueprint can ensure that the house has the right foundation and structure so it will not fall down, and it has the correct hidden spaces to accommodate the plumbing, electrical, gas, and so on. Also, the many different people that build the house using the blueprint—such as framers, electricians, bricklayers, painters, and so on—know that if they follow the blueprint, their part of the work should not cause problems for the other workers.

Similarly, you could build your own network—write your own software, build your own networking cards, and so on—to create a network. However, it is much easier to simply buy and use products that already conform to some well-known networking model or blueprint. Because the networking product vendors build their products with some networking model in mind, their products should work well together.

I left you the reference from [**Cisco Press - The TCP/IP and OSI Networking Models**](https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1757634)